# Customise Wordpress Rest API Search endpoint

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

## Wordpress Rest API Search Endpoint

** Endpoint = /wp-json/wp/v2/search?search=term **

Is it possible to edit the return object for the results of this wordpress rest search endpoint? I am trying to add featured image to the post object that is returned.

Example below is how you would edit the regular post object, but this does not effect the object returned by the search endpoint.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_field( 'post', 'featured_image_src', array(
'get_callback' => function ( $post_arr ) {
$image_src_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_arr\['featured_media'\], 'medium' );

            return $image_src_arr[0];
        },
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => null
    ) );

} );
```

I've tried changing ...register_rest_field( 'post'.... to ...register_rest_field( 'search'... but this does not change anything as search is not an object type.

Adding &embed to the url returns the post object but not with the featured image included. The embedded array includes "self" and that is where the other post object data is but wpfeatruedimage is not there, only media ID.

Any help would be  great.

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field( 'search-result', 'featured_image_src', array(
        'get_callback' => function ( $post_arr ) {               
            $image_src_arr = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_arr['id']);    
            return $image_src_arr;            },
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => null
    ) );
} );
```